# Syntax error on token "}", { expected after this token android

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a timer for the android app I'm developing and am trying to make a test timer that will display the time left. I have tried a lot of websites but none work. Here is the complete code from the activity:

```
package com.hunter.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Settings extends Activity {

//intent to return to menu from settings
public void back (View view) {

    Intent back = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(back);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    //calls on textview
    final TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    //length of timer
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        //counts the milliseconds
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         //displays seconds remaining
         text1.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     //displays when timer finishes
     public void onFinish() {
         text1.setText("done!");
     } //<================================== error
     this.start();
    } //<============================== error
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "start" call needs to be made on the object instance as follows:

```
(new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {    
     // your code here..
}).start();
```

In you code, the "this.start()" is within the class definition.  It is not within any method.

Note that the "(" and ")" I have included are optional.  I prefer to add them for clarity so that the object instance itself is contained.  You could however do the following:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) { 
    // your code here...   
}.start();
```